# React Native Network Request Failed randomly (HTTPS + URL)

Tags: react-native, xmlhttprequest, fetch

So I have this strange error with React Native, where randomly network requests hangs.

This can be provoked by either listening to a remote audio file, or creating a new user and logging into the app.

This is an issue for all React Native versions at least over 0.59 (havent tested below that).

So to give a bit of background:

When I navigate to a new tab, I load data for that tab. Randomly it will just hang, and give a Network Request Failed with no further information. Once that arrives, and I navigate from and back to the screen it starts working again, until a couple minutes later where it will randomly hang one request.

Tried putting an aggressive timeout on it to provoke an early escape, but seems the native layer has to throw a Network Request Failed for it to start working again.

I've been biting nails for weeks trying to debug this issue, as it's limiting the release of the application.

Comment: Any reproducible code?

Comment: iOS, Android or both? If reproducible on Android, try running 'adb logcat' in terminal and see if it logs any useful info about the error.

Comment: Have you got error callback for every API calls, when you navigate to new tabs nd loads data. It might be case, callback is not handled properly, switching tabs may be causing this issue.